# For a projective scheme over a base, when do cones and fibers commute?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Definitions**: Let $R$ be a ring and suppose $X\subset \Bbb P^n_R$ is a closed subscheme cut out by the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ on $\Bbb P^n_R$. Then the largest homogeneous ideal of $X$ in $R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ is $I=\Gamma_*(\mathcal{I})=\bigoplus \pi_*(\mathcal{I}(d))$ (this can be written as the saturation of any other ideal cutting out $X$), and we can write $X=\operatorname{Proj}(R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/I)$. Define $C(X)$, the cone on $X$, as $\operatorname{Proj}(R[x_0,\cdots,x_n,x_{n+1}]/(I))$. The fiber of $X$ over a point $r\in \operatorname{Spec} R$ is defined to be $X_r=\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(r)\times_{\operatorname{Spec} R} X$, which can be seen to be $\operatorname{Proj}((R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/I)\otimes_R \kappa(r))$.

### Question: When is $C(X_r)\cong C(X)_r$ as subschemes of $\Bbb P^n_{\kappa(r)}$?

**Motivation**: This seems like something that ought to be intuitively true with no conditions if you think about the geometric constructions these two operations are supposed to represent. But one has to verify this from the algebraic definitions, and it wouldn't surprise me if some assumptions were required (flatness, for instance). Unfortunately, I've made this claim in an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3679045/is-the-affine-cone-of-a-flat-projective-scheme-again-flat/4114054#4114054) without having a full proof in hand and the OP there has rightly pointed out my lack of rigor. After several days of thinking about it, I don't have a good fix, and I've decided to ask for help.

**Progress**: Define $J\subset \kappa(r)[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ to be the kernel of $$R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\otimes_R \kappa(r) =  \kappa(r)[x_0,\cdots,x_n] \to (R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/I)\otimes_R \kappa(r)$$ (equivalently the image of $I\otimes_R \kappa(r)\to R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]\otimes_R \kappa(r)$). Then $X_r=\operatorname{Proj}(\kappa(r)[x_0,\cdots,x_n]/J^{sat})$, and $$C(X_r)=\operatorname{Proj}(\kappa(r)[x_0,\cdots,x_{n+1}]/(J^{sat})).$$ On the other hand, $C(X)_r=\operatorname{Proj}((R[x_0,\cdots,x_{n+1}]/(I))\otimes_R \kappa(r))$, and writing $R[x_0,\cdots,x_{n+1}]/(I)=\bigoplus x_{n+1}^d R[x_0,\cdots,x_{n}]/I$, we see that $(R[x_0,\cdots,x_{n+1}]/(I))\otimes_R \kappa(r)\cong \kappa(r)[x_0,\cdots,x_{n+1}]/(J)$. Since two homogeneous ideals cut out the same subscheme of $\Bbb P^{n+1}_{\kappa(r)}$ if and only if they have the same saturation, we need to show that $(J^{sat})^{sat} = (J)^{sat}$.

One way to attack this would be to show that if $I\subset R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ is saturated, then $S^{-1}I\subset S^{-1}R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ is saturated for $S\subset R$ multiplciatively closed and the image of $I$ in $(R/P)[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ is saturated for $P\subset R$ prime. The first is claim doable, but I'm stumped on the second claim.