# Hartshorne III Exercise 9.5:What is the family of cones of a family of varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Through reading Hartshorne's book I coarsely understand the flat family of varieties as a flat flat morphism between two varieties and the important objects are those fibers. But if that is the definition then the exercise 9.5 really confuses me.

In the part a of this exercise we need to find a flat family of projective varieties $\{X_t\}_t$ such that their projective cones $\{C(X_t)\}_t$ is not a flat family.

OK, $X_t$s is a flat family means we have a flat morphism $f:X\to Y$(here $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ being projective), and $X_t=f^{-1}(t)$. But then how to understand $C(X_t)$s as a **family**? I know that if we set $P=(0,\cdots,0,1)\in \mathbb P^{n+1}$, then we have a canonical morphism $C(X)\setminus P\to X$, and we can compose it with $f$ to get a morphism $g:C(X)\setminus P\to Y$. Does he mean $C(X_t)=g^{-1}(t)$? So I need to find an example such that $g$ is not flat?

I wonder if these understandings are right. I'm pleased to accept corrections if I have misunderstood something. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something along "What is the family of cones of a family of varieties" would be a more descriptive title?

Comment: @red_trumpet Thanks for suggestion, I have edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about is a key part of later portions of the problem: given a flat projective family $X\to T$ with fibers $X_t$, how does one construct a flat projective family $X'\to T$ with fibers $C(X_t)$? You'd like to say that the cone on $X$ works, but proving that you can commute the operations of cones and fibers [is difficult](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4124781/for-a-projective-scheme-over-a-base-when-do-cones-and-fibers-commute). Your attempt is not really on the right track.

It's considerably easier to show that some collection of varieties cannot be the members of a flat family, though: recall theorem III.9.9 which states that a projective family is flat iff the Hilbert polynomials for each member $X_t$ are the same. So you need to be on the lookout for a projective family where all the members $X_t$ have the same Hilbert polynomial, but the Hilbert polynomials for $C(X_t)$ are not all the same. (Just to be clear, when I say $C(X_t)$, I mean that $X_t\subset\Bbb P^n_t$ is a projective scheme over a field, so take the cone in that setting.) To do this, you'll need to start by investigating the relationship between the Hilbert polynomials of $X_t$ and $C(X_t)$: once you do, you should notice something interesting which will tell you what to look for next.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By the way, can I say generally flat family is just a flat morphism between two varieties(not necessarily projective)? And I can see in this exercise we need to find a projective morphism in order to make $X_t$ projective. Is that true?

Comment: Definitions vary by setting - I'm sure you can find instances in the literature where "flat family" means just a flat morphism $X\to T$. Hartshorne is only considering flat projective families here, though. That is, a flat map $X\to T$ which factors as $X\to \Bbb P^n_T\to T$ where $X\to\Bbb P^n_T$ is a closed immersion and $\Bbb P^n_T\to T$ is the natural projection.  (PS: if this was helpful, please consider voting up and/or accepting this answer.)

Comment: Thanks again. Usually I 'd like to figure out all details before I accept an answer.

Comment: No problem - are there details in your question which remain unaddressed?

Comment: No details remaining. Thank you for your patient and your elaborate answer.